# Retrieve inserted row using pg-promise npm module in Express.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, pg-promise

I am inserting a user row into Postgres from Express.js like as follows:

```
db.none("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (${incoming.email}, crypt(${incoming.password}, gen_salt('bf')))",{
    incoming: { email: qemail, password: qpwd}
  }
).then(function (data) {
  // data is null
});
```

The email and password come from the query parameters on the React.js frontend. I use this query for the signup action on my application and wanted to know if I could get this newly added user back from this same query. I just felt that making another get request right after the signup to get the user info was inefficient, which I do for my login action. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append `RETURNING *` to your query, and replace [none](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#none) with method [one](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#one).

```
const row = await db.one("INSERT INTO users(email, password) VALUES(${incoming.email}, 
                          crypt(${incoming.password}, gen_salt('bf'))) RETURNING *",
    {
        incoming: { email: qemail, password: qpwd}
    }
);

// row = the newly inserted row
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the query add `RETURNING *`. This should return the newly added query. ([postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/dml-returning.html)).

In your query:

```sql
"INSERT INTO users (
    email, password
  ) VALUES (
    ${incoming.email}, crypt(${incoming.password}, gen_salt('bf'))
  ) RETURNING *"
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I had to pick the other one as the answer due to more detail! I appreciate it!